# Lists coding issue

Tags: python, list

I am trying the following code but now my professor wants a small update to this. I have a list of labels

```
[good,noise,mixed,silent]
```

A combination of these values makes up new lists such as these.

```
[good,good,noise,noise,good,good,silent]
```

My first problem was I had to convert the bad or noise to good if the previous 2 values were good also .

I have tried the following code. Now he asked me to take the 2 as window and pass it as variable. Basically if the win=3 that means if the previous 3 values are good then the noise or mixed value should be replaced by good.

If win=5 then if previous 5 values of a label are good then the current noise or mixed label should become good.

```
list10=['silent','good','good','good','noise','good','good','mixed','good','good','good','silent','good','mixed']

def predUpdate(new_list):
    update_list=new_list.copy()

    for a in range(len(new_list) - 2):
        if (new_list[a] == 'good' and new_list[a + 1] == 'good' and (
                new_list[a + 2] == 'mixed_noise' or new_list[a + 2] == 'noise')):
            update_list[a + 2] = 'good'
    return update_list

print (list10)
print (predUpdate(list10))
```

Initial Output:

```
['silent', 'good', 'good', 'good', 'noise', 'good', 'good', 'mixed', 'good', 'good', 'good', 'silent', 'good', 'mixed']
```

=====================

```
['silent', 'good', 'good', 'good', 'good', 'good', 'good', 'good', 'good', 'good', 'good', 'silent', 'good', 'mixed']
```

=====================

This is for window value 2 (2 values of good). How can I do the same for 3 or 5 or any random value given of good?

Comment: Is this homework?

Comment: Yes . I am not able to get the logic. I know we have to iterate over one more time I think but can't figure out.

Comment: A hint: basically, your current approach is "hardcoded" to work for 2 only. Now, let me ask you a question: if i said look at win=1000, would you write something like `new_list[a + 1]` upto `new_list[a + 1000]` by hand? (I hope the answer is no). In that case, what's a way to compare more values without having to write it all out?

Comment: exactly my point. I didnt know though that we could compare multiple values to single value . Now i do. thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here you go

```
list10=['silent','good','good','good','noise','good','good','mixed','good','good','good','silent','good','mixed']

def predUpdate(new_list,k):
    update_list=new_list.copy()

    for a in range(len(new_list) - k):
        if (new_list[a:a+k] == k*['good'] and new_list[a+k]!='silent'):
            update_list[a + k] = 'good'
    return update_list

print (list10)
print (predUpdate(list10,3))
```

Comment: Small change. The if statement should be changed to
`
if (new_list[a:a+k] == k*['good'] and new_list[a+k]!='silent'):
`

Comment: My Bad. Let me fix this.

Answer (score 0):

The optimal way:

- Note that you've seen 0 consecutive good values
- Start with an empty result list
- Iterate over the list
- If the value is good, note that you've seen one more consecutive good value
- Otherwise:
- - If the value is mixed or bad, and you've seen at least N consecutive good values, change it to good
- - Then note that you've seen 0 consecutive good values
- Add the current value (possibly changed) to the result list

The suboptimal way (but closer to your original solution):

- Start with an empty result list
- Iterate over indices of the start array (`i`)
- If we're at at least `N`-th element, and the element is mixed or bad: see if all of the elements in the window ending with `i-1` are `"good"`. You can do this very easily using the `all` function: `all(x[j] == "Good" for j in range(i - win, i))`. If so, change the element to `"good"`
- Add the current value (possibly changed) to the result list

Comment: I like the optimal way. It's clear for my understanding. thank you.